# Word wrapping in a ListCtrl (or ObjectListView)

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, word-wrap, objectlistview

I have a wxListCtrl (Actually it's an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/index.html)), set with LC_REPORT with two columns.

Is it possible to word wrap the first column of text when it reaches the end of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with a ObjectListView (see their [FAQ](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/faq.html)), because ListCtrl doesn't support multiline entries.

It is possible, however, using UltimateListCtrl

```
import wx
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap
import wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl as ULC   

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

        self.list = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        items = ['A', 'b', 'a really really long line that if would be nice if it could word-wrap']
        colWidth = 100
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "AA", width=colWidth)
        for item in items:
            item = wordwrap(item, colWidth, wx.ClientDC(self))
            self.list.InsertStringItem(0, item)

app = wx.App(False)
frm = Frame(None, title="ULC wordwrap test")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

wxListCtrl is fairly limited in its features.  In order to do anything more than the basic, you should consider 'upgrading'  to wxGrid, which has a wealth of features.

Comment: I am currently using ObjectListView which is a ListCtrl, and it's implemented. So I need wrapping in this object. If I did 'upgrade' to wxGrid, how would it transition? Does wxGrid behave in the same way as OLV? (Takes a list of objects)

Comment: What is 'ObjectListView"?  The name does not look like something in wxWidgets.

Comment: There is a link in my question. It wraps wxListView.