# wxPython ListCtrl wrap words on resize

Tags: python, list, wxpython, word-wrap, listctrl

I am trying to create an application using wxPython.

I have a `sizer` and inside that `sizer` I have added a `ListCtrl` with some list items. When I shrink the `sizer` (window), items in the list are displayed with dots `...`.

I want to wrap words and content shold be placed in multiple lines for each item as the window is resized. I have tried `ListCtrl`, `UltimateListCtrl` and `ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin`. But not giving desired output.

Is there any way to achieve this using `ListCtrl` or `UltimateListCtrl` or any other widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it with UltimateListCtrl.

Following code refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733549/word-wrapping-in-a-listctrl-or-objectlistview), and made some improvement to support auto update for colum dragging.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap
import wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

        self.list = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.items = ['list', 'list', 'I want to wrap words and content shold be placed in multiple lines for each item as the window is resized']
        colWidth = 200
        self.colWidthPad = 5
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "test", width=colWidth)
        for item in self.items[::-1]:
            item = wordwrap(item, colWidth - self.colWidthPad, wx.ClientDC(self))
            self.list.InsertStringItem(0, item)

        self.list.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_DRAGGING, self.onDrag)

    def onDrag(self, evt):
        col = evt.GetItem().GetColumn()
        width = self.list.GetColumnWidth(col)
        itemCount = self.list.GetItemCount()

        for i in range(0, itemCount):
            text = wordwrap(self.items[i], width - self.colWidthPad, wx.ClientDC(self))
            self.list.SetStringItem(i, col, text)


app = wx.App(False)
frm = Frame(None, title="ULC wordwrap test")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I found this to be unreliable under OSX:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyaaypm4e9o8mf6/Screenshot%202014-02-20%2020.04.39.png   https://www.dropbox.com/s/kt4o2ehw4qrkc1h/Screenshot%202014-02-20%2020.06.43.png https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpxw3z1w3l8i35p/Screenshot%202014-02-20%2020.08.12.png

Comment: @GreenAsJade I don't have the OSXenvironment, could you please help to have a try with self.list.Refresh() called in onDrag()?

Comment: Sure.  It did not appear to noticeably help.   As soon as I size the left column to about "I want to" width, I get ...s   At slightly larger widths, I get the top or bottom cut off.   At "reasonable" widths, it looks fine.

Comment: @GreenAsJade  I guess `...` issue can be resolved by enlarge the value of `self.colWidthPad`, but I have no idea about why the top or bottom cut off.

Comment: Seems like a dodgy implementation of UltimateListCtrl for OSX eh?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Yes,maybe it is :)

Comment: thnx @Jerry_Y.. I implemented wordwrap in a loop as you suggested.. and its working for me on Windows..